# What wrong with my beginner code?

Tags: java, class

I cant understand whats wrong with my code. In this code i getting errors like this when im trying to assign a value to a variable within a class. Also System.out.println doesnt work in this classes:
1.Identifier expected
2.Unexpected token
3.Unknown class "windows"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}

class building{
    int apart_num;
    apart_num = 3;
}

class apartments{
    double area;
    int lightbulb;
    int windows;
    windows = 4;
}

interface construct_building{

}

interface construct_apartments{

}
```

Comment: Is everything in **one** file? Also you can't have a `main` on its own. It needs to be in some class.

Comment: You can't have the declaration and assgnation of variables like this outside a method. It can be done in one line only (or in a method)

Comment: Yes everething is in one file.

Comment: @QBrute So i should  declarate viriable like this? 'int windows = 4;'?

Comment: @MikitaKazlouski That's the typical approach if you're giving it an immediate value. There are multiple other issues as has been pointed out, however.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring an instance member on one line :

```
int apart_num;
```

and then assign a value to it :

```
apart_num = 3;
```

The problem is that this is done outside a method, those statement can't be separated, you can't assign a variable previously declare outside a block statement so.

Do it in a one line (declaration and assignation) :

```
class building{
    int apart_num = 3;
}
```

or with a constructor

```
class building{
    int apart_num;

    public building(){
        apart_num = 3;
    }
}
```

or in a block statement

```
int windows;
{ //a block statement
    windows = 4;
}
```

---

Then, if this code is not a class, you need to do it.

```
public MyClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){ ... }
    ...

    class Building { //inner class (will exist only inside of a MyClass instance

    }

    static class Apartment { // a nested class, exist whitout a MyClass instance

    }
}

class Level { //A class that have nothing to do  with MyClass and that can not be public.

}
```

Where MyClass is the name of the file (MyClass.java)